# Javascript is not loaded after location.href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've got this ajax request. Basically it downloads a file (after redirect to this page).

```
  $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("IsFileSetForDownload", "UserLogin")',
            success: function (result) {
            if (result == "true")
               top.location.href = "DownloadFile"
                    },
            cache: false
            });
```

Page also contains few input fields, some additional JS. Everything works fine.
 Except with IE8. After top.location.href javascript stops working (page is reloaded). Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Are you wanting it to continue running your script after the browser has redirected on to a different location? Or something else?

Comment: I expect it to stay in the same page with JavaScript working (Like it does with other browsers). 
P.S. "DownloadFile" is MVC Controller method which returns file.

Comment: What happens if you just try `top.location` instead, or `window.location`? (On IE8 and your other browsers)

Comment: Already tried this. No difference whatsoever.

Comment: Have suggested a workaround as an answer, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to create an `iframe` instead of redirecting the browser.

Simply replace:

```
    if (result == "true")
        top.location.href = "DownloadFile"
    }
```

with:

```
    if (result == "true")
        var iframe = $("<iframe />").attr("src", "DownloadFile");
        $("body").append(iframe);
    }
```

This should result in the browser no longer assuming it's navigating to a new location.

Comment: This is exactly what i did. Worked nicely.